# How to know if wifi is connected with new Android Lollipop wifi management

Tags: android, android-wifi, android-5.0-lollipop

I need to connect my mobile by wifi to a connected device. This hot spot have not internet.

Before 5.0 I did like this to check if I was connected to the wifi

```
ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                            NetworkInfo mWifi = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
                            if(mWifi.isConnected()&& wifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getNetworkId()==addedNetwork)
```

But now with the 5.0 version of android, when I check isConnected it always returns false because of the none connectivity to internet.

How can I manage this case ?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this out but as per the google [docs](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0.html#Wireless) this should work

```
    ConnectivityManager cManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Activity.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkRequest.Builder builder = new Builder();
    //Indicates that this network should be able to reach the internet.
    builder.addCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET);
    NetworkRequest build = builder.build();
    cManager.requestNetwork(build, new NetworkCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onAvailable(Network network) {
            super.onAvailable(network);
            // do what you want to do here
        }
    });`
```